# Invoke PHP file which is in webserver through phonegap

Tags: php, cordova

I am trying to build an android app for the existing php web application. I just want a clear roadmap on how to access PHP files which are placed in webserver, using phonegap. I read that we can invoke these files using Ajax calls.. if this is the case,
1. Will the PHP code need to be changed 
2. Will output be the same as it looks as web application (HTML content)

Kindly let me know if i need to add more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No your PHP code probably won't need to be changed, Yes it will return the same content. When you type in a URL to a webpage, it sends a request to the server and the PHP returns HTML or whatever data you tell it to return (the response). AJAX can make a call to the server in a similar fashion of the GET request your browser makes, so whatever your PHP script is returning to the browser, it will return to ajax as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing my questions.. I'll try to proceed for further steps.. in case i have questions i would need your help again :)

Comment: Hello, I have improved my question can anyone please help me in that